# Code to force mobile devices to stream mp3 files from website?

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a site that contains mp3 for people to download on their desktop but can only stream on their mobile devices. I've search all day only for some kind of solution. Can anybody give some pointers?

Info:
Site uses php/jscript
So far only apple devices are able to sorta stream the file (not sure if thats whats happening)

Comment: Why not use the HTML5 <audio> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that much about this sort of stuff. But I would think that HTML5 would be the best way of going about this.

I have never heard of a website written in PHP or JavaScript that can stream an MP3 file on a mobile device. I know that a service called GrooveShark streams on mobile devices using HTML5. Maybe that's worth a look.